# How to add custom Attribute Property

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create a custom extension which will be able to add new Attribute Property in (Catalog->Attiributes->Manage Attributes->Add new attribute-> in field 'Attribute Properties'). It will be drop down with two options and file upload button.

If you know some information where can I read about this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you want requires a lot of code and it involves changing the core behavior a lot.
I don't recommend this because you can easily break stuff.
Instead I suggest using something that Magento already has.
A dropdown/multiselect product attribute can have a custom source for the options. I mean, instead of the options being managed from the `Attiributes->Manage Attributes` section, they can come from anywhere else.
They can come from an extenral source, or a different table or you can even hard code them.
So I recommend creating your own entity, that you can manage through a simple CRUD module and contains an id, a title, a file and what ever else you need and the values you enter for those entities can be used as attribute options.

[Here is an example](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html) on how you can create such an attribute.
In the example, the option values are hard coded in the method `getAllOptions`, but instead of hard coding them you can read the entries from a table and return them. Magent will take care of the rest.

If you don't want to write too much code, you can build your module (CRUD and attribute) by using this [module creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9).
You will find documentation on how to use the extension [here](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki). The most important part you need, the one that allows you to create the product attribute is [here](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki/entity-products). Make sure you set to `yes` the field `Make entity a product attribute`.

[EDIT]
In case you really need to do this in the options screen here are some pointers on what you can do:
You need to change the template for the options and add your new fields.
For this create a new admin theme so you won't edit the core code. [Here is how you can change the admin theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates).
Then copy the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml` to your new theme and add your new inputs in there. The template for each option line is contained in the js variable `templateText`. Try to follow what's already there and add your fields.

Then you have to add in the table `eav_attribute_option_value` columns corresponting to each new field you add.
Then you need to rewrite the `_saveOption` method from the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Attribute` class. That's the one that handles the attribute option saving. (the method is actually found in the `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute` but you need to rewrite it for the child class mentioned above) and make it take into consideration the fields you added.

honestly this is a complicated process and like I said, it's prone to errors. But you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are good examples. But my task is to create this functional in Attiributes->Manage Attributes section, like an attribute extantion(((

Comment: @sergey I edited my answer with some pointers on how you can achieve what you need. And as a future reference, you should not accept an answer if it didn't help you solve the problem.